# Pandas generate report with titles and specific structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this (represent a investment portfolio):

```
data = {'category':['stock', 'bond', 'cash', 'stock',’cash’],
        'name':[‘AA’ , ‘BB’,  ‘CC’,  ‘DD’, ’EE’],
        'quantity':[2,  2,  10,  4, 3],
        'price':[10, 15, 4, 2, 4],
        'value':[ 20, 30, 40,8, 12],

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to generate a report in a text file that looks like this :

```
Stock:   Total: 60
Name quantity price value
AA           2          10      20
CC           10         4      40

Bond:   Total: 60
Name quantity price value
BB           2          15      30

Cash:   Total: 52
Name quantity price value
CC           10          4      40
EE            3          4      12
```

I found a way to do this by looping through a list of dataframe but it is kind of ugly, I think there should be a way with iterrow or iteritem, but I can’t make it work.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop by `groupby` object and write custom header with data:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('category', sort=False):
    with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'{i}:   Total: {g["value"].sum()}\n')
        (g.drop('category', axis=1)
          .to_csv(f, index=False, mode='a', sep='\t', line_terminator='\n'))
        f.write('\n')
```

Output:

```
stock:   Total: 28
name    quantity    price   value
AA  2   10  20
DD  4   2   8

bond:   Total: 30
name    quantity    price   value
B   2   15  30

cash:   Total: 52
name    quantity    price   value
CC  10  4   40
EE  3   4   12
```